# My ReactJS web app need to turn hybrid : Ionic or React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I actually have a progressive web app built with ReactJS. I need to turn it in native app (mainly to use notifications). 
I read a lot of articles, but I didn't read people with this dilemma :

If I have code base in ReactJS, when Choose Ionic, when choose React Native.

**My fear with Ionic :**

- I will need to convert a lot of component to Ionic Component
- I heard cordova is not very stable

**My fear with React Native :**

- More time-consuming : I need to duplicate and convert  my presentational components. (maybe
  more ?) or use [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)

One of you did already had the same experience ?

What framework will be the more easy implement from my reactjs app ? What is your opinion ?

Comment: I think it will be easier to convert to Ionic. For the most part, with Ionic you're still building a web application. With React Native, you have to change your way of thinking a bit because it's really a native mobile app, just written in JavaScript. I highly recommend checking out React Native (or Expo, which provides a lot of tools to simplify building React Native apps) but in this case I'd probably just go with Ionic.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that Ionic-React uses Capacitor instead of Cordova

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! Indeed, Ionic looks more easy to switch.
@JamesBrightman my new question : Why not only use Capacitor for my goal?